# java.lang.StackOverflowError? in java

Tags: java

i get this " java.lang.StackOverflowError "
when i run the code 
but the problem come when i put a big number like (7,10)

this is the code that i write

The code for calculate The Ackermann Function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m, n, s;
    Scanner maher = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" the code for calculate The Ackermann Function ");
    System.out.println(" Enter first number M");
    m = maher.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" Enter Second number N");
    n = maher.nextInt();
    System.out.println("A(" + m + " , " + n + ") = " + Ack(m, n) + " \n");
}
public static int Ack(int m, int n) {
    if (m == 0) {
        return n + 1;
    }
    if (m != 0 && n == 0) {
        return Ack(m - 1, 1);
    }
    if (m != 0 && n != 0) {
        return Ack(m - 1, Ack(m, n - 1));
    }
    return 0;
    // This code written by Maher Al Shammari 212542270 // KFU
}
```

I try to change the type to long but the problem doesn't solve ,,,,

Comment: You *do* realize that there's no way any computer has enough room to store that many levels, right? Saying that Ackermann(7,10) is huge is a massive understatement.

Comment: This is kind of the point of the Ackermann function. Creating insane amounts of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You have created "endless" or at least "too deep" recursion.
This is the problem here.

Not to talk of the fact that this function is known to grow very very very quickly.
So you will need BigInteger for it (not int, not long). Probably though even BigInteger will not get you too far.

Comment: @Maher Yes, check your termination conditions. Probably you missed something there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure BigInteger won't help; I doubt Ackermann(6,6) fits in a BigInteger, much less Ackermann(7,10). Actually, just doing a quick lookup, I don't think Ackermann(4,4) fits in a BigInteger either.

Comment: @Maher My gut instinct is you can't. Ackermann's isn't primitively recursive, I doubt you can convert it into an iterative form easily. Memoising intermediate results would help it execute faster but do nothing for recursion depth.

Comment: @DennisMeng That makes me wonder, is there a way to estimate how many digits Ackermann's has for a given input?

Comment: @Maher As others noted this function is basically illustrating that computers are not that super powerful for some kinds of tasks which can be posed :) even by some simply defined and innocently looking functions / like this monster here :) /.

Comment: @millimoose Maybe? I think for 99.9999% of people who've heard of the function, "too many" is all you need to know after about Ackermann(4,4)

Comment: @Maher you solve it by creating a spare universe to store the number in.

Comment: @Maher Check here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function If you don't need to express it in decimal form (or in some other numberic form), you have pretty good expressions/formulas for it. See e.g. this part "The Péter-Ackermann function can also be expressed in terms of various other versions of the Ackermann function". But of course that is not same as calculating it through the use of a computer. It is something else - expressing it as a mathematical formula.

Comment: @Maher You can't. The point is that the number is just too big.

Comment: @Boann Do you think if i store the number in file text and read from there ,,, is it work or makes the code more complex

Comment: @Maher You would need a hard disk bigger than all of reality, and many lifetimes of the Universe to compute it. It's TOO BIG.

Answer (score 2):

- **Stack overflow** means **too many nested method calls**.
- Your logic seems right, its surely due many recursive calls involved.
- Anyways, I think you should be happy to see result for **ACK(4, 4)**.
- **ACK(7, 10)** - really? asking too much... its like calling **NQueens(16)** :P

Comment: That last point isn't exactly true; NQueens(16) is much *much* less of a challenge.

Comment: Thinks @Mitesh ,,,,,,,

Comment: @DennisMeng agreed.. I think it should be TowerOfHanoi(16 disks) :D

Comment: Try again, still small fry. Ack(4,4) can't fit, even if you took all of the computers in the world. TowerOfHanoi(16) fits in my cell phone.

Comment: Neways I hope my message is conveyed ;)

Comment: Hopefully. You're welcome to use the analogy in my previous comment if you feel like it.

Comment: Do you think if i store the number in file text and read from there ,,, is it work or makes the code more complex

Comment: but how will u represent them in Java..
They wont even fit in BigInt??

Answer (score 0):

You can try manipulating the JVM stack size.  I'm not sure that this will help in the end, but if you have a machine with a lot of memory, you can increase both the stack and heap and push the failure out further.

The default stack size is 384KB.  You manipulate it using the `-Xss` parameter to the JVM.  For example, `-Xss512k` sets the stack size to 512KB.

Comment: It's not a bad idea in the general case, but for this, the problem is that the number the OP is trying to calculate is too big; the computer can't store that many digits *period*, much less have room for all of the recursion levels (there's no way to make it iterative either)

Comment: @DennisMeng that would be a problem.  Ultimately he's going to overflow anything short of an arbitrary-precision data container.  From the wikipedia entry:  Its value grows rapidly, even for small inputs. For example A(4,2) is an integer of 19,729 decimal digits.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the Wikipedia too; A(4,4) has 2^(2^(65536)) digits. It's so huge, the *exponent* can't fit anywhere.

Comment: (edit: Well, it has that many bits. If you want digits, dividing by 4 lowballs it, and that's still, you know, big enough to get the point across)